# Woocommerce: product images are all different size

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The thumbmail pictures all have a different size. See:
[image]
[image]

I know that it is mainly due to the image sizes (for example the yellow product does not have the height of the thumbnail). However, it would be great if it is possible to make sure that it centers or puts a white space around it so that at least it feels that they are of the same size. My settings are:[image] and i'm using shopkeeper child time.

Any advice on how to make this more clean would be very helpfull.

Comment: Not sure about Woocommerce but does your theme have calls to `add_image_size()`? The fourth parameter is a boolean T/F that defaults to false, meaning it doesn't crop by default. Sounds like you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try with CSS:

```
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
object-fit: cover; /* I use cover but contain also works */
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It's something very simple what you ask so it's weird it's not standard in woocommerce. Anyway, I found a plugin that does this and it works for me. Tried it on 2 different shops. Both on the latest wordpress version.

You can choose the color of the background and the alignment. After activating the plugin you do have to run a thumbnail regeneration plugin.

Edit sorry forgot to include the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/square-thumbnails/